# Вопрос по geojson

Tags: python, geojson

Сделал себе geojson на основе КПТ Росреестра и отрисовал в "Конструктор карт Яндекс", вот [ссылка](https://yandex.ru/maps/?um=constructor%3Aa326e8b283304c2937a244c10fc3b40901ba0481f3e2206ea4139adc157b7f50&source=constructorLink) на карту. **Первый вопрос**, как сделать, при создании geojson, полигон с полностью прозрачной заливкой, что бы можно было "тыкать" по карте (внутри полигона), читал, что это делает **"fill-opacity":0**, но не получается? **Второй вопрос**, некоторые земельные участки имеют несколько контуров, на карте можно найти хаотичные линии, по таким думаю нужно создавать MultiPolygon, верно ли думаю (хотя бы направление)?
Вот код, с помощью чего делаю geojson:

```
import geojson
import pandas as pd

excel_file = r'F:\python_1\non-contractual\geo_KPT.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

feature_collection = geojson.FeatureCollection([])

coords_dict = {}
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    kad_num = row['Кадастровый номер']
    x = row['Координаты x']
    y = row['Координаты y']

    if kad_num in coords_dict:
        coords_dict[kad_num].append([y, x])
    else:
        coords_dict[kad_num] = [[y, x]]

for kad_num, coords_list in coords_dict.items():
    feature = geojson.Feature(
        geometry=geojson.Polygon([coords_list]),
        properties={"description": f"{kad_num}",
                    "fill":"#ff931e",
                    "fill-opacity":0,
                    "stroke":"#e6761b",
                    "stroke-width":"1",
                    "stroke-opacity":0.9}
    )
    feature_collection['features'].append(feature)

with open(r'F:\python_1\non-contractual\geojson\1.geojson', 'w') as f:
    geojson.dump(feature_collection, f)
```

Ниже скрин с "Конструктор карт Яндекс", характеристики полигона:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**По первому вопросу**,лучше всего делать из линий, а не из полигонов, проблем в этом случае не будет. **По второму вопросу**, конструктор карт от яндекса не поддерживает MultiPolygon (как я понял), как и MultiLineString, для MultiPolygon лучше сделать так, построить на карте обычный полигон и построить от него внешний контур (это и есть MultiPolygon), далее сохранить и экспортировать в geojson, там уже посмотреть как эти границы делаются.